# How to generate a power set of a given set?

Tags: algorithm, math, powerset

I am studying for an interview and I stumbled upon this question online under the "Math" category.

Generate power set of given set:

```
int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};  
int N = 5; 
int Total = 1 << N;
for ( int i = 0; i < Total; i++ ) { 
 for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
  if ( (i >> j) & 1 ) 
      cout << A[j]; 
   } 
 cout <<endl;

 }
```

Please I do not want an explicit answer. I just want clarifications and hints on how to approach this problem.

I checked power set algorithm on google and I still do not understand how to address this problem.

Also, could someone reiterate what the question is asking for.

Thank you.

Comment: Power set of a set={a,b} is the set consisting of all possible combination of representing elements of the set taken any or none at a time. Here,P(s)={{a},{b},{ab},{}};

Comment: Very interested in recursive algorithm for this problem!

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19891145/1740808

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Power set of a set A is the set of all of the subsets of A.`

Not the most friendly definition in the world, but an example will help :

Eg. for `{1, 2}`, the subsets are : `{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}`

Thus, the power set is `{{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}}`

---

To generate the power set, observe how you create a subset : you go to each element one by one, and then either retain it or ignore it.

Let this decision be indicated by a bit (1/0).

Thus, to generate `{1}`, you will pick `1` and drop `2` (10).

On similar lines, you can write a bit vector for all the subsets :

- {}    -> 00
  {1}   -> 10
  {2}   -> 01
  {1,2} -> 11

To reiterate : A subset if formed by including some or all of the elements of the original set. Thus, to create a subset, you go to each element, and then decide whether to keep it or drop it. This means that for each element, you have 2 decisions. Thus, for a set, you can end up with `2^N` different decisions, corresponding to `2^N` different subsets.

See if you can pick it up from here.

Answer (score 17):

> Create a power-set of: `{"A", "B", "C"}`.

---

**Pseudo-code:**

```
val set = {"A", "B", "C"}

val sets = {}

for item in set:
  for set in sets:
    sets.add(set + item)
  sets.add({item})
sets.add({})
```

---

**Algorithm explanation:**

1) Initialise `sets` to an empty set: `{}`.

2) Iterate over each item in `{"A", "B", "C"}`

3) Iterate over each `set` in your `sets`.

3.1) Create a new set which is a copy of `set`.

3.2) Append the `item` to the `new set`.

3.3) Append the `new set` to `sets`.

4) Add the `item` to your `sets`.

4) Iteration is complete. Add the empty set to your `resultSets`.

---

**Walkthrough:**

Let's look at the contents of `sets` after each iteration:

Iteration 1, item = "A":

```
sets = {{"A"}}
```

Iteration 2, item = "B":

```
sets = {{"A"}, {"A", "B"}, {"B"}}
```

Iteration 3, item = "C":

```
sets = {{"A"}, {"A", "B"}, {"B"}, {"A", "C"}, {"A", "B", "C"}, {"B", "C"}, {"C"}}
```

Iteration complete, add empty set:

```
sets = {{"A"}, {"A", "B"}, {"B"}, {"A", "C"}, {"A", "B", "C"}, {"B", "C"}, {"C"}, {}}
```

The size of the sets is 2^|set| = 2^3 = 8 which is correct.

---

**Example implementation in Java:**

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> powerSet(List<T> input) {
  List<List<T>> sets = new ArrayList<>();
  for (T element : input) {
    for (ListIterator<List<T>> setsIterator = sets.listIterator(); setsIterator.hasNext(); ) {
      List<T> newSet = new ArrayList<>(setsIterator.next());
      newSet.add(element);
      setsIterator.add(newSet);
    }
    sets.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(element)));
  }
  sets.add(new ArrayList<>());
  return sets;
}
```

Input:  `[A, B, C]`

Output: `[[A], [A, C], [A, B], [A, B, C], [B], [B, C], [C], []]`

Comment: If you added `{}` at the beginning (rather than the end) then you wouldn't have to explicitly insert the singleton sets at each pass through the outer loop.

Comment: @JohnColeman Hi John, if we added an empty set at the beginning, then we would iterate over the sets one too many times. After the first iteration we would have {{"A"},{"A"}} which is incorrect. Inserting the empty set is also done outside any loops. Do you mind sharing some code to explain?

Comment: But if you have `{}` at the beginning, wouldn't you have `{"A"}, {}` after one pass? You are taking the existing `sets` and creating a copy of each set in it, to which you add the new item. Since you would be adding "A" to the copy -- I don't see how "A" sneaks into the empty set. After all, when you do this with "B" in your loop you get {"A","B"} while still having {"A"} -- that {"A"} isn't replaced by {"A","B"}. You should insert the empty set outside of any loop -- but *before* the loops, in which case adding the singletons inside the loop is superfluous.

Comment: @JohnColeman If I start with an empty set `{{}}`, then as I iterate over the sets I will take the empty set and append 'A' to it. I will then add a new set containing 'A' to the existing sets. Running the code with your suggestion I get the following after the first iteration: `[[], [A], [A]]` as expected. Running the new algorithm on {'A', 'B', 'C'} I get `[[], [C], [B], [B, C], [A], [A, C], [A, B], [A, B, C], [A], [A, C], [A, B], [A, B, C], [B], [B, C], [C]]`

Comment: You say "I will then add a new set containing 'A' to the existing sets" -- but *why* would you still do that? The point of my comment is that explicitly adding the item as a singleton (step 4 in your pseudocode) isn't needed if you initialize with the empty set

Comment: @Cristian Why are you using a List and not a Set? isn't it better to use a Set in order to ensure that there are no duplicates?

Comment: @SarahM I use a `List` to demonstrate that this algorithm doesn't produce duplicates

Comment: Very great algo, but it will not work for input containing duplicate element and subset shouldn't have duplicate?

Comment: What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score 12):

Power set is just set of all subsets for given set. It includes all subsets (with empty set). It's well-known that there are 2<sup>N</sup> elements in this set, where `N` is count of elements in original set.

To build power set, following thing can be used:

- Create a loop, which iterates all integers from 0 till 2<sup>N</sup>-1
- Proceed to binary representation for each integer
- Each binary representation is a set of `N` bits (for lesser numbers, add leading zeros). Each bit corresponds, if the certain set member is included in current subset.

Example, 3 numbers: `a`, `b`, `c`

```
number binary  subset
0      000      {}
1      001      {c}
2      010      {b}
3      011      {b,c}
4      100      {a}
5      101      {a,c}
6      110      {a,b}
7      111      {a,b,c}
```

Comment: why are we converting into binary? I am not getting that.

Comment: @PoojaKhatri each bit in the binary number indicates whether an element is present in the current subset or not. Check out the top rated answer for a better explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you need to generate all subsets. For a set of size n, there are
2<sup>n</sup> subsets.

One way would be to iterate over the numbers from 0 to 2<sup>n</sup> - 1
and convert each to a list of binary digits, where `0` means exclude
that element and `1` means include it.

Another way would be with recursion, divide and conquer.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I'm very interested in more about the recursive technique.  This was an old college Lisp assignment that I never figured out.  And I'm still puzzled.

Comment: @ScottBiggs So am I.. This thing is just confusing!

Comment: You can see some recursive examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332412

Answer (score 3):

Generating all combination of a set (By including or not an item). 
explain by example:
3 items in a set (or list). The possible subset will be:

```
000   
100   
010   
001
110
101
011
111
```

The result is 2^(number of elements in the set).

As such we can generate all combinations of N items (with python) as follows:

```
def powerSet(items):

    N = len(items)

    for i in range(2**N):

        comb=[]
        for j in range(N):
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                comb.append(items[j])
        yield comb

for x in powerSet([1,2,3]):
    print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You Get Something Like This by Implementing the top rated Answer.

```
def printPowerSet(set,set_size):

    # set_size of power set of a set
    # with set_size n is (2**n -1)
    pow_set_size = (int) (math.pow(2, set_size));
    counter = 0;
    j = 0;

    # Run from counter 000..0 to 111..1
    for counter in range(0, pow_set_size):
        for j in range(0, set_size):

            # Check if jth bit in the 
            # counter is set If set then 
            # pront jth element from set 
            if((counter & (1 << j)) > 0):
                print(set[j], end = "");
        print("");
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# Solution**

Time Complexity and Space Complexity: O(n*2^n)

```
 public class Powerset
    {


        /*
         P[1,2,3] = [[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
             */
        public  List<List<int>> PowersetSoln(List<int> array)
        {

            /*
                We will start with an empty subset
                loop through the number in the array
                         loop through subset generated till and add the number to each subsets

              */

            var subsets = new List<List<int>>();
            subsets.Add(new List<int>());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
            {
                int subsetLen = subsets.Count; 
                for (int innerSubset = 0; innerSubset < subsetLen; innerSubset++)
                {
                    var newSubset = new List<int>(subsets[innerSubset]);
                    newSubset.Add(array[i]);
                    subsets.Add(newSubset);
                }

            }

            return subsets;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Sample Java Code:

```
void printPowerSetHelper(String s, String r) {
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        printPowerSetHelper(s.substring(1), r + s.charAt(0));
        printPowerSetHelper(s.substring(1), r);
    } 
    if (r.length() > 0) System.out.println(r);
}

void printPowerSet(String s) {
    printPowerSetHelper(s,"");
}
```