# Python recursive function to display all subsets of given set

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion, functional-programming

I have the following python function to print all subsets of a list of numbers:

```
def subs(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return [l]
    res = []
    for sub in subs(l[0:-1]):
        res.append(sub)
        res.append([l[-1]])
        res.append(sub+[l[-1]])
    return res

li = [2, 3, 5, 8]
print(subs(li))
```

This returns:

```
[[2], [8], [2, 8], [5], [8], [5, 8], [2, 5], [8], [2, 5, 8], [3], [8], [3, 8], [5], [8], [5, 8], [3, 5], [8], [3, 5, 8], [2, 3], [8], [2, 3, 8], [5], [8], [5, 8], [2, 3, 5], [8], [2, 3, 5, 8]]
```

Which is not the expected answer. It looks like python takes the list l into the function by reference. So when I append l[-1], it appends the last element of original list, not the smaller list sent into the recursive method. Is there any way to solve this?

This could possibly be solved using tuples but I'm wondering if there is a solution using lists.

Comment: What is the expected answer? This looks to be what you're looking for. Obviously this method accumulated a lot of duplicates in the process as well.

Comment: Do you want something like `[list(itertools.permutations(li[:x])) for x in range(len(li))]` in a one-dimension list ?

Comment: @Cocksure my mistake, python is actually doing what it's supposed to do :). I thought it was taking in the list by reference in the function. So l[-1] would be always 8 in above case. However l[-1] is 3,5,8 in the recursive calls. This modified code solves the issue:def subs(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return [l]
    res = []
    subsets = subs(l[0:-1])
    res = res+subsets
    res.append([l[-1]])
    for sub in subsets:
        res.append(sub+[l[-1]])
    return res

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
def subs(l):
    if l == []:
        return [[]]

    x = subs(l[1:])

    return x + [[l[0]] + y for y in x]
```

Results:

```
>>> print (subs([1, 2, 3]))
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I want the result sorted in lexicographical order?

Comment: @Nidhi You might notice this solution sorts the result in inverse lexicographical order. Just permute the return to get lexicographical order: `return [[l[0]] + y for y in x] + x`

Answer (score 3):

There is a convenient Python module to help:

```
import itertools
def subs(l):
    res = []
    for i in range(1, len(l) + 1):
        for combo in itertools.combinations(l, i):
            res.append(list(combo))
    return res
```

The results are:

```
>>> subs([1,2,3])
[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the recipe for `powerset` given on the [`itertools` module page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)—but their version actually returns an iterator, which is much nicer than a list for potentially huge results.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no problem with Python call by reference as I originally thought. In that case l[-1] would be 8 in all recursive calls. But l[-1] is 3, 5, 8 respectively in the recursive calls. This modified function solves the issue:

```
def subs(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return [l]
    res = []
    subsets = subs(l[0:-1])
    res = res+subsets
    res.append([l[-1]])
    for sub in subsets:
        res.append(sub+[l[-1]])
    return res
```

returns:

```
[[2], [3], [2, 3], [5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [2, 3, 5], [8], [2, 8], [3, 8], [2, 3, 8], [5, 8], [2, 5, 8], [3, 5, 8], [2, 3, 5, 8]]
```

Comment: It misses the empty set ('[]').

Answer (score 1):

Improving on @Miguel Matos answer

```
def subsets(set_inp):
    if set_inp == []:
        return [[]]
    x = subsets(set_inp[1:])

    return sorted( x + [[set_inp[0]] + y for y in x])
print(subsets([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

using @Miguel Matos idea
we can get these in  lexicographical order by,

```
def foo(l, p = [], d = {}):
    if len(l)==0: 
        return [[]]
    
    x = foo(l[:-1])
    
    return x+ [[l[-1]] + y for y in x]
```

> returns
>
> [[], [1], [2], [2, 1], [3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1], [4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 2, 1], [4, 3], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using comprehensions or for-loops by using lambda functions and `map`.

I consider this a proper 'functional' powerset function in Python:

```
def powerSet(input):


# at tree leaf, return leaf
if len(input)==0:
    return [[]];

# if not at a leaf, trim and recurse
# recursion is illustrated as follows:
# e.g. S = {1,2,3}
# S_trim = S without first element:
# {(),(2),(3),(2,3)}
# S_trim concatenated with first element:
# {(1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,2,3)}
# we keep the character sliced from front and concat it 
# with result of recursion

# use map to apply concatenation to all output from powerset

leading = (input[0])
new_input = input[1:len(input)]


ps1 = list((powerSet(new_input)))
# concatenate over powerset-ed set
ps2 = map(lambda x: [leading]+x,ps1) 

ps_list = list(map(lambda x: list(x),ps2))

return ps1+ ps_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on the answers provided by @Miguel and @Abdul...the following function insures a lexicographically ordered output.

```
def subset(A):
    if A == []:
        return [[]]
    sub = subset(A[:-1])
    return sub + [rem + [A[-1]] for rem in sub] 

tests = [[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
for test in tests:
    print(subset(test))
```

```
RESULT

[[]]
[[], [1]]
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2]]
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```