# Python Program that return sublists of a list

Tags: python

Please I want to design a function that return all possible subset of a list.  Here is the code I tried

```
def mylist(list1):
    for I in list1:
        print(i)
```

Comment: can you please update your question to include an example input with the corresponding desired output?

Comment: without an example output, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332412/python-recursive-function-to-display-all-subsets-of-given-set

Comment: You basically want the power set...check here using itertools library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035595/powersets-in-python-using-itertools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all the subsets of a set, with exactly n elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374626/how-can-i-find-all-the-subsets-of-a-set-with-exactly-n-elements)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is the powerset, [itertools' recipe page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes) has a nice, concise, memory-safe way to do that:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    """
    powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)
    """
    s = list(iterable)

    # note that this returns an iterator rather than a list
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s,n) for n in range(len(s)+1))
```

Worth pointing out that finding a powerset is exponential O(2^n). Also, this question had been previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374626/how-can-i-find-all-the-subsets-of-a-set-with-exactly-n-elements).

Answer (score 0):

Just using iterative method for doing this as 
i looped from `0` to `2^(length of list)` and select each element based on the value of the loop counter

That is if the loop counter is 5 we select the first and third element

as 5 in binary is represented as `101` the we select the index elements with 1 in binary likewise for 7 we need first three elements `111`

```
def mylist(list1):
    num=len(list1)
    result=[]
    for i in range(1<<num):
        temp=list()
        index=0
        while i:
            if i&1==1:
                temp.append(list1[index])
            index+=1;
            i>>=1
        result.append(temp)
    return result

print(mylist([1,2,3]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

also you might want convert this function to a generator as the returned list will be huge if the inputlist contains large number of values