# Understanding recursion using power set example

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have written a simple piece of code to print all subsets of a set using recursion. I have a hard time understanding the output. For example, the first line in the output shows an empty set and a singleton of 3 whereas I was expecting an empty set and singleton of 1 to be printed followed by an empty set, singleton of 1, singleton of 2 etc. However, that is not what gets printed. I do not know how to visualize recursion tree. Are there any general techniques to accomplish the visualisation? I tried drawing a tree but it quickly gets confusing.

```
def subsets(self, nums):
        inp = nums
        out = []
        result=[]
        def helper(inp,out,index):
            if index==len(inp):
                result.append(out)
                return
            helper(inp,out,index+1)
            helper(inp,out+[inp[index]],index+1)
            print(result)
        helper(inp,out,0)
        return result
```

The output from the print statement for the input '[1,2,3]' is shown below

```
[[], [3]]
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3]]
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3]]
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3]]
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you also included the input that led to your included output.

Comment: change where you print to the beginning of your function for example and/or add extra prints

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python recursive function to display all subsets of given set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332412/python-recursive-function-to-display-all-subsets-of-given-set)

Comment: Stepping through the program with a debugger should solve this problem fairly fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an "indentation" parameter to your function, while you explore it, you can immediately see which function calls which:

```py
def subsets(nums):
        inp = nums
        out = []
        result=[]
        def helper(indent,inp,out,index):
            print(f"{indent}->helper({inp},{out},{index})")
            if index==len(inp):
                result.append(out)
                return
            helper(indent+'--',inp,out,index+1)
            helper(indent+'--',inp,out+[inp[index]],index+1)
        helper('',inp,out,0)
        return result
```

The result will look like:

```
->helper([1, 2, 3],[],0)
--->helper([1, 2, 3],[],1)
----->helper([1, 2, 3],[],2)
------->helper([1, 2, 3],[],3)
------->helper([1, 2, 3],[3],3)
----->helper([1, 2, 3],[2],2)
------->helper([1, 2, 3],[2],3)
------->helper([1, 2, 3],[2, 3],3)
--->helper([1, 2, 3],[1],1)
----->helper([1, 2, 3],[1],2)
------->helper([1, 2, 3],[1],3)
------->helper([1, 2, 3],[1, 3],3)
----->helper([1, 2, 3],[1, 2],2)
------->helper([1, 2, 3],[1, 2],3)
------->helper([1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3],3)
```

So you can immidiately see why you get [] first--you get it when you go all the way through the list without including anything in the results. You get [3] next because you backtrack to the call where you add 3 and then go to the end. You get [2] by backtracking a bit further, to where you include 2 in the output, and then down the path that doesn't add 3. Then you get [2,3] because you backtrack one level up, to the call that has 2 included in the result, and this time go to the path that adds 3.

It probably isn't the easiest way to compute a power-set, though. There is a one-to-one correspondence between the powerset of size n and the binary numbers between 0 and 2**n-1. For each number, the 1-bits indicate which elements to include in the set. So you can also compute the powerset like this:

```py
def subsets(nums):
    return [
        [nums[j] for j, b in enumerate(reversed(format(i, 'b'))) if b == '1']
        for i in range(2**len(nums))
    ]
```

It runs in exponential size, but so does the recursive version, and that is unavoidable when the output is exponential in the size of the input.

Comment: Wow, this is super helpful. Thanks a ton!