# Is there a algorithm to print all arrengments of subsequences of an array?

Tags: c, algorithm, combinatorics, enumeration

I am working with combinatorics and I would like to know if there is an algorithm that prints all arrangments of subsequences of a given array.   That is, if I give to this algorithm  the sequence "ABCDEF" it will print :

A,
B,
C,
D,
E,
F,
AB,
AC,
AD,
AE,
AF,
BC,
BD,
BE,
BF,
CD,
CE,
CF,
DE,
DF,
EF,
ABC,
ABD,
ABE,
ABF,
ACD,
ACE,
ACF,
ADE,
ADF,
AEF,
BCD,
BCE,
BCF,
BDE,
BDF,
BEF,
CDE,
CDF,
CEF,
DEF,
ABCD,
ABCE,
ABCF,
ABDE,
ABDF,
ABEF,
ACDE,
ACDF,
ACEF,
ADEF,
BCDE,
BCDF,
BCEF,
BDEF,
CDEF,
ABCDE,
ABCDF,
ABCEF,
ABDEF,
ACDEF,
BCDEF,
ABCDEF,

or for a more simple case, if i give it 1234, it will print:

1,2,3,4,12,13,14,23,24,34,123,124,134,234,1234.

As you can see it is not an arbitrary permutation it is only the permutation of the last members of a subsequence in a way it still reains a subsequence.

I have tried to make a function in c that does this but i got really confused, my idea would be to make a int L that keeps the size of the subsequence,and another tree integers one that keeps the head of the subsequence, one that marks the separation from the head and one that slides trought the given number of characters, but it gets too confused too quickly.

Can anyone help me with this ?

my code is:

```
int Stringsize( char m[] ){

     int k;
     for(k=0;;k++){
     if( m[k] == '\0') break;    
     }
return (k-1);

}


void StringOrdM(char m[]){
    int q,r,s,k; 
    for(k=0;k<=Stringsize(m);k++)
       for(q=0;q<=Stringsize(m);q++)
          for(s=q;s<=Stringsize(m);s++ )
              printf("%c",m[q]);
          for(r=q+1; r<=Stringsize(m) && (r-q+1)<= k ;r++ )
              printf("%c", m[r] );

}
```

And for ABCD it prints A,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,D,AA,AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CC,CD,DD,... so it is not right because it keeps repeating the A 4 times the B three times and so on, when it should have been A,B,C,D,AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD,...

Comment: Simple.  Count in binary up to (1<<n)-1.  So if you have four items, count up to 15, with each bit pattern being a selection of the elements.  You'll get 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, 0110, 0111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111.  Each bit is a true/false value as to whether to include that element of the array.

Comment: Alternatively, use recursion... each permutation of length `n` in array `A[]` starting with given element `i` is simply `i` appended with the permutations of length `(n-1)` of the "array" `&A[i+1]`

Comment: Could you clarify how could i do this in recursion ? How exactly do i embed permutations in a recursion ?

Comment: You asked the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700705/how-do-i-program-a-function-that-prints-all-subsequences-of-a-string-in-shortlex so obviously something is missing here for you to accept an answer. Please elaborate. If you have trouble using proposed code in your program, then explain more about that, instead of asking just "can you do it for me". If the problem you have with using is different from the original problem, then consider making a separate question of it.

Comment: There are no permutations here, nothing similar to that concept. You want to print all subsequences of a sequence. If all elements are different, this amounts to printing all subsets of a set.

Comment: @Yunnosch if you had read my comments you would see that i'am having difficulties using the proposed code in my program because ideally this program should run for an arbitrary string of characters, and the proposed solution makes it an array of integers, and when i try to change from an array of integers to an array of characters the code stops working, mainly in the part of calling sizeof of the array.

Comment: @Yunnosch Your attitude is that of a hypocrite that uses a straw man fallacy by saying that i have not appointed my problem whith the proposed solution and that i have been asking for other people to "do every thing for me", when in fact i have never made such a request, in fact I have proposed my own code to show in what specifically I am having difficulties with and am open to any anwsers.

Comment: @Yunnosch  it is just that as I am trying to make an actual program with the sugestions, and I ask for some more specific advice, for it doesn't help me if when someone sugests the right thing i am not able to understand and implement their sugestion, so I proposse that you get a little bit less trigger happy to say that someone is asking "can you do it for me", when they are actually more interested in understanding how would such and such a thing be done/implemented and what is the logic behind that, to me your comment is of null content.

Comment: *and when i try to change from an array of integers to an array of characters the code stops working, mainly in the part of calling sizeof of the array*. That's hardly anyone else's fault. If you have a problem with the basics of the C language, perhaps you should try learning them. Stackoverflow could be of help here. Ask a question, show your change and explain how exactly it stops working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a power set of a given set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365954/how-to-generate-a-power-set-of-a-given-set)

Comment: You are looking for the power set. There are many implementations out there. Here is one: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:C

Comment: @FelipeDilho did my code has any problem, i need to know to fix it.

Comment: @HeIs As I read into your code and run it I found no problems, it is easier to understand than the code that I finished some hours ago and that relies way more heavily in using a bunch of nested for loops and a sorting algorithm to sort the resulting array by string length.

Comment: @FelipeDilho I have edited it, now you can get the result of "123456789".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on torstenvl's answer I did this code and It works perfectly.

If there is any problem let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
   char str[] = "1234"; 
   size_t len = strlen(str);                 // Array length (in elements)
   char *A = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
   strcpy(A,str);

   size_t elbp = (1<<len) - 1;             // Element selection bit pattern
   size_t i, j;                            // Iterators
   int a = 0, b = 0, n = 0;
   char **arr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (10000));      //allocating memory

if (A[0] >= 'A' && A[0] <= 'Z')          //If the string given is "ABCD...." transfer 'A' to '1' ; 'C' to '3' ...etc
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        A[i] = A[i] - 'A' + '1';

// Cycle through all the bit patterns
for (i = 1; i<=elbp; i++)
{
    arr[b] = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

    // For each bit pattern, store in arr[b] the 'checked' elements
    for (j = 0, a = 0; j < len; j++) 
        if (i & (1<<j))
            arr[b][a++] = A[j]; 
    b++;
}

int *num = calloc(sizeof(int) ,10000);

for (i = 0; i < b; i++) 
    num[i] = strtol(arr[i], NULL, 10);     //convert char to int

for (i = 0; i < b; i++)                   //sort array numbers from smallest to largest
    for (a = 0; a < i; a++)
        if (num[i] < num[a])
        {
            n = num[i];
            num[i] = num[a];
            num[a] = n;
        }

char *result = calloc(sizeof(char),10000);

for (i = 0, a = 0; i<b; i++)
    a += sprintf(&result[a], "%d,", num[i]);     //convert int to char and store it in result[a]

result[a - 1] = '\0';    //remove the last ','
len = strlen(result);

if (str[0] >= 'A' && str[0] <= 'Z')              //if the string given is "ABCD..." transfer '1' to 'A' ; '12' to 'AB' ; '13' to 'AC'.....etc
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(result[i] != ',')
            result[i] = 'A' + (result[i] - '1') ;

  ///test
  printf("%s",result);

  return 0;
}
```

the output for "1234":

```
1,2,3,4,12,13,14,23,24,34,123,124,134,234,1234
```

the output for "123456789":

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,34,35,36,37,38,39,45,46,47,48,49,56,57,58,59,67,68,69,78,79,89,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,134,135,136,137,138,139,145,146,147,148,149,156,157,158,159,167,168,169,178,179,189,234,235,236,237,238,239,245,246,247,248,249,256,257,258,259,267,268,269,278,279,289,345,346,347,348,349,356,357,358,359,367,368,369,378,379,389,456,457,458,459,467,468,469,478,479,489,567,568,569,578,579,589,678,679,689,789,1234,1235,1236,1237,1238,1239,1245,1246,1247,1248,1249,1256,1257,1258,1259,1267,1268,1269,1278,1279,1289,1345,1346,1347,1348,1349,1356,1357,1358,1359,1367,1368,1369,1378,1379,1389,1456,1457,1458,1459,1467,1468,1469,1478,1479,1489,1567,1568,1569,1578,1579,1589,1678,1679,1689,1789,2345,2346,2347,2348,2349,2356,2357,2358,2359,2367,2368,2369,2378,2379,2389,2456,2457,2458,2459,2467,2468,2469,2478,2479,2489,2567,2568,2569,2578,2579,2589,2678,2679,2689,2789,3456,3457,3458,3459,3467,3468,3469,3478,3479,3489,3567,3568,3569,3578,3579,3589,3678,3679,3689,3789,4567,4568,4569,4578,4579,4589,4678,4679,4689,4789,5678,5679,5689,5789,6789,12345,12346,12347,12348,12349,12356,12357,12358,12359,12367,12368,12369,12378,12379,12389,12456,12457,12458,12459,12467,12468,12469,12478,12479,12489,12567,12568,12569,12578,12579,12589,12678,12679,12689,12789,13456,13457,13458,13459,13467,13468,13469,13478,13479,13489,13567,13568,13569,13578,13579,13589,13678,13679,13689,13789,14567,14568,14569,14578,14579,14589,14678,14679,14689,14789,15678,15679,15689,15789,16789,23456,23457,23458,23459,23467,23468,23469,23478,23479,23489,23567,23568,23569,23578,23579,23589,23678,23679,23689,23789,24567,24568,24569,24578,24579,24589,24678,24679,24689,24789,25678,25679,25689,25789,26789,34567,34568,34569,34578,34579,34589,34678,34679,34689,34789,35678,35679,35689,35789,36789,45678,45679,45689,45789,46789,56789,123456,123457,123458,123459,123467,123468,123469,123478,123479,123489,123567,123568,123569,123578,123579,123589,123678,123679,123689,123789,124567,124568,124569,124578,124579,124589,124678,124679,124689,124789,125678,125679,125689,125789,126789,134567,134568,134569,134578,134579,134589,134678,134679,134689,134789,135678,135679,135689,135789,136789,145678,145679,145689,145789,146789,156789,234567,234568,234569,234578,234579,234589,234678,234679,234689,234789,235678,235679,235689,235789,236789,245678,245679,245689,245789,246789,256789,345678,345679,345689,345789,346789,356789,456789,1234567,1234568,1234569,1234578,1234579,1234589,1234678,1234679,1234689,1234789,1235678,1235679,1235689,1235789,1236789,1245678,1245679,1245689,1245789,1246789,1256789,1345678,1345679,1345689,1345789,1346789,1356789,1456789,2345678,2345679,2345689,2345789,2346789,2356789,2456789,3456789,12345678,12345679,12345689,12345789,12346789,12356789,12456789,13456789,23456789,123456789
```

the output for "ABCDEF":

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,BC,BD,BE,BF,CD,CE,CF,DE,DF,EF,ABC,ABD,ABE,ABF,ACD,ACE,ACF,ADE,ADF,AEF,BCD,BCE,BCF,BDE,BDF,BEF,CDE,CDF,CEF,DEF,ABCD,ABCE,ABCF,ABDE,ABDF,ABEF,ACDE,ACDF,ACEF,ADEF,BCDE,BCDF,BCEF,BDEF,CDEF,ABCDE,ABCDF,ABCEF,ABDEF,ACDEF,BCDEF,ABCDEF
```

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment above, one solution is simple:  count in binary up to `(1<<n)-1`.

So if you have four items, count up to 15, with ***each bit pattern being a selection of the elements***. You'll get `0001`, `0010`, `0011`, `0100`, `0101`, `0110`, `0111`, `1000`, `1001`, `1010`, `1011`, `1100`, `1101`, `1110`, `1111`. Each bit is a true/false value as to whether to include that element of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  size_t len = sizeof A / sizeof A[0];    // Array length (in elements)
  size_t elbp = (1<<len) - 1;             // Element selection bit pattern
  size_t i, j;                            // Iterators

  // Cycle through all the bit patterns
  for (i = 1; i<=elbp; i++) {
    // For each bit pattern, print out the 'checked' elements
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      if (i & (1<<j)) printf("%d ", A[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If you want the elements sorted shortest to longest, you could always store these results in a string array (using `sprintf()`) and then sort (using a stable sorting algorithm!) by string length.

Comment: how does "Element selection bit pattern" work ? i'm not familiarized with this operation it in C.

Comment: I edited to emphasize what I'm talking about.  `elbp` is the maximum integer value that will hold `n` bits, where `n` is the size of your array.  That way, you can iterate `i` from `1` to `elbp` and it will hold every possible bit pattern in between.  **Once you do that** you can treat each bit pattern in `i` as a list of checkboxes to see if that element is selected in that permutation, e.g., if your value is `11000` in binary, then the first and second elements, `A[0]` and `A[1]`, are "checked" so you'd print them both out.

Comment: Fundamentally, you're trying to find out whether or not each element is in a given permutation of your array.  "whether or not" is a binary question, so you can easily model it with a bit pattern.  Then it's just a matter of making sure you're hitting every permutation -- but that comes free if you're using a bit pattern, because **every** permutation of a set of bits is covered by iterating through their values from minimum to maximum.

Comment: The logic seems right what i wasn't understanding  was how the (<<) operator works because i have never seen it before in C.

Comment: It shifts left.  If I have `1` and shift it left `0`, or `1<<0`, then my resulting value is binary `0000 0001`.  If I shift it left by `7`, or `1<<7`, then I have binary `1000 0000`.  The `&` operator evaluates to non-zero **if and only if** there are matching bits in the operands.  So `i & (1<<j)` evaluates to non-zero (i.e., true) if `i` has the `(j+1)`th bit set (counting from the right).

Comment: Ok, i am not beeing able to string print the results of this code because when i change the type of the array from int to char the sizeof function does not work anymore !!!!

Comment: Can you do the recursion style type of Algorithm ? I'm having difficulties to put toguether your code and my main function.

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned in a comment above that if you didn't want to use a bit pattern to find all permutations, and sort the results according to whatever criteria you'd like, you could also use a recursive algorithm.

I suspect this is a homework assignment, and you only asked for an algorithm, so I left some of the key code as an exercise for you to finish.  However, the algorithm itself is complete (the key parts are just described in comments, rather than functional code being inserted).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void printpermutations(const int *A, const size_t n, const char *pfix, const size_t rd);


int main(void) {
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  size_t n = sizeof A / sizeof A[0];    // Array length (in elements)
  size_t i;                             // Iterator

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    printpermutations(A, n, "", i);
  }

  return 0;
}


// Recursive function to print permutations of a given length rd,
// using a prefix set in pfix.
// Arguments:
//   int *A       The integer array we're finding permutations in
//   size_t n     The size of the integer array
//   char *pfix   Computed output in higher levels of recursion,
//                which will be prepended when we plunge to our
//                intended recursive depth
//   size_t rd    Remaining depth to plunge in recursion
void printpermutations(const int *A, const size_t n, const char *pfix, const size_t rd) {
  size_t i;
  char newpfix[strlen(pfix)+22];  // 20 digits in 64-bit unsigned int
                                  // plus a space, plus '\0'

  if (n < rd) return;             // Don't bother if we don't have enough
                                  // elements to do a permutation

  if (rd == 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      // YOUR CODE HERE
      // Use printf() to print out:
      //   A string, consisting of the prefix we were passed
      //   Followed immediately by A[i] and a newline
    }
  }

  else {
    strcpy(newpfix, pfix);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      // YOUR CODE HERE
      // Use sprintf() to put A[i-1] and a space into the new prefix string
      //   at an offset of strlen(pfix). 
      // Then, call printpermutations() starting with the ith offset into A[],
      //   with a size of n-i, using the new prefix, with a remaining
      //   recursion depth one less than the one we were called with
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combinations, or k-combinations, are the unordered sets of k elements chosen from a set of size n.
Source: http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/combinations.html
This is the code:

```
unsigned int next_combination(unsigned int *ar, size_t n, unsigned int k)
{
    unsigned int finished = 0;
    unsigned int changed = 0;
    unsigned int i;

    if (k > 0) {
        for (i = k - 1; !finished && !changed; i--) {
            if (ar[i] < (n - 1) - (k - 1) + i) {
                /* Increment this element */
                ar[i]++;
                if (i < k - 1) {
                    /* Turn the elements after it into a linear sequence */
                    unsigned int j;
                    for (j = i + 1; j < k; j++) {
                        ar[j] = ar[j - 1] + 1;
                    }
                }
                changed = 1;
            }
            finished = i == 0;
        }
        if (!changed) {
            /* Reset to first combination */
            for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                ar[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return changed;
}
```