# Python or math: How to count all possible combinations of a list's elements?

Tags: python, math

Say there is a list `[1,2,3,4,5]`, I would need to get the count of all possible combinations of the elements (or 'sub-lists'), e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, ..., 123, 124, ..., 12345`.

I know how to get `nCr`, the count of combinations of `r` elements of a list with total `n` elements.
Python 3.8 or above:

```
from math import comb
p, r = 5, 2
print(comb(p, r))
```

Then I could do `nC1 + nC2 +...+ nCn`. But is there a better/faster way?

```
p, result = 5, 0
for r in range(1, 6):
    result += comb(p, r)
print(result)
```

Would appreciate your answers.

Comment: This indeed seems like a [math.se] problem. I don't know it offhand, but I'll bet there's a simple formula.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a power set of a given set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365954/how-to-generate-a-power-set-of-a-given-set)

Comment: Thanks. It is a "power set" question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific sum is equal to `2^n -1` :-)

Comment: While this is true, a little bit of context would be needed (probably linked to binomial coefficents in some way) see @jprebys answer

Comment: This is only true for unique elements. If there's repetition it's more complicated.

Comment: Right. Thanks. Is there a term for this num?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27266/simplify-sum-of-combinations-with-same-n-all-possible-values-of-k

Comment: OP's question is sufficiently detailed for context.

Answer (score 3):

This concept is called a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) in mathematics, and it refers to all subsets of a given set. Your question refers to the size of the power set which is `2^n` where `n` is the size of your original set. This total includes the empty set, so as C4stor said, your total would be `2^n - 1`.

The above answer works if the input has all unique elements. If there are repeated elements then take the product of (count + 1) of every element, and again subtract one at the end to remove the empty set.

E.g. [1,1,1,2,2,3]: our counts are 3, 2, 1, so our answer is 4 * 3 * 2 - 1 = 23.

The idea is that for each element, you can have anywhere from 0 up to count(element) in your sublists.

Comment: This answer is assuming unique elements. If there's repetition it's incorrect.

Comment: The OP does not provide any rules, just an example dataset, so I take the half-full-cup side : OP should have given more specific instructions :=)

Comment: Thanks. (2^n-1) should be enough. If there are duplicate elements, I could simply use set() to get the unique ones then the power set count.

Comment: @Nov05 You know your use case better than we do, but combinations can still have repeated elements - `[1,1]` is, in general, a valid length-2 combination of `[1,1,1]`

Comment: @EdwardPeters You could give an answer for 2 cases, one for the case of unique elements, the other for the case of duplicate elements. But thanks all the same!