# Find all candidates

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to get the following output using C# using loops, I want to always start from A, then create all possible paths that consist of B, C, D and E, something like the following:

A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   E   D
A   B   D   C   E
A   B   D   E   C
A   B   E   C   D
A   B   E   D   C

A   C   B   D   E
A   C   B   E   D
A   C   D   B   E
A   C   D   E   B
A   C   E   B   D
A   C   E   D   B

A   D   B   C   E
A   D   B   E   C
A   D   C   B   E
A   D   C   E   B
A   D   E   B   C
A   D   E   C   B

A   E   B   C   D
A   E   B   D   C
A   E   C   B   D
A   E   C   D   B
A   E   D   B   C
A   E   D   C   B

I have written a sample C# code, but I am always stuck and not getting the entire string.

Comment: Then please show the code that you already have...

Comment: You are looking at 'power sets'  http://www.programminglogic.com/powerset-algorithm-in-c/

Comment: I assumed the letters as integers:

      int[] dest = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            int h = dest.Length + 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < dest.Length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j < h; j++) { 
                Console.Write(dest[i]);
                Console.Write("\n");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890781/creating-a-power-set-of-a-sequence

Comment: Thank you Hristo and all the guys, but it must be always consisting from all elements, I am not sure it is a power set

Comment: Can you share your CODE, then we can check. Why you stuck and not getting the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the next loop variables are not equal to any of the previous loop variables like this:

```
char[] arr = { 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };

foreach (var b in arr)
{
    foreach (var c in arr)
        if (c != b)
            foreach (var d in arr)
                if (d != c && d != b)
                    foreach (var e in arr)
                        if (e != d && e != c && e != b)
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat('A', b, c, d, e));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```