# Get all subsequences of a sequence

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array and I need all possible subarrays (segments or subsequences) with the exception of the empty one. This is ***not a power set***, since every subarray has only elements that were contiguous in the input array.

For example, for input `new int[]{1,2,3}`, the output would be:

```
 new int[]{
   new int[]{1},
   new int[]{1,2},
   new int[]{1,2,3},
   new int[]{2},
   new int[]{2,3},
   new int[]{3}
 }
```

Note that `{1,3}` is not there because **i don't want all subsets (the power set)**, just all subsequences.

I would prefer a solution using a single LINQ statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890781/creating-a-power-set-of-a-sequence - realized this is a probable dupe

Comment: Can the people voting this down care to given an explanation as to why?

Comment: I imagine it's because your question reads like "I have a requirement, and I'd like someone to write the code for me"

Comment: @jdphenix That question is to get a power set (all combinations). What I want is all subsequences.

Comment: From your post: "I need the power set of the array" - did you mean to write a different question?

Comment: @NetMage I edited the title and body based on my understanding of the problem.

Comment: @jdphenix The example isn't a power set, it doesn't include `{ 1, 3 }`.

Comment: It is always useful to put the proper C# types in questions. `{1,2,3}` is not a valid C# object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a power set of a Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890781/creating-a-power-set-of-a-sequence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your source is a `List` (if not, convert to a `List`) then you can do:

```
var srcl = src.ToList();
var ans = Enumerable.Range(0, srcl.Count).SelectMany(start => Enumerable.Range(1, srcl.Count-start).Select(count => srcl.GetRange(start, count)));
```

Using a natural `ArraySegment` extension:

```
public static class ArrayExt {
    public static IEnumerable<T> Segment<T>(this T[] src, int start, int count) => new ArraySegment<T>(src, start, count);
}
```

You can have this return an array of arrays:

```
var ans = Enumerable.Range(0, src.Length).SelectMany(start => Enumerable.Range(1, src.Length-start).Select(count => src.Segment(start, count).ToArray()));
```

But `List` is generally preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Although NetMage's solution is correct, I ended up writing my own extension method that uses `Array.Copy` for performance:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get all subsequences of the given sequence.
/// {1,2,3}=>{{1,2},{1,2,3},{2,3}}
/// </summary>
public static T[][] GetAllSubsequences<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    var list = (collection as T[]) ?? collection.ToArray();
    return list.SelectMany((x, i) => list.Skip(i).Select((z, j) =>
          {
              var arr = new T[j + 1];
              Array.Copy(list, i, arr, 0, j + 1);
              return arr;
          })).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Is there really a performance issue with `GetRange`? Besides error checking, `List.GetRange` actually uses `Array.Copy` internally.